# Difference between these 2 ways of declaring JS properties

Tags: javascript

I'm currently using the following pattern to create JS modules to be used. However, I can't figure out if there is any difference, or any benefit, to doing it in the first style vs the second.

***1st way***

```
var UI = UI || {};
(function () {
var BtnShape = function (x, y, width, height, size, color, text)
{
    this.initialise(x, y, width, height, size, color, text);
}
var p = BtnShape.prototype;

    p.isEnabled = false; //<--------------
    p.initialise = function (x, y, width, height, size, color, text)
    {}
UI.BtnShape = BtnShape;
})();
```

***2nd way***

```
var UI = UI || {};
(function () {
var BtnShape = function (x, y, width, height, size, color, text)
{
    this.initialise(x, y, width, height, size, color, text);
}
var p = BtnShape.prototype;

    p.initialise = function (x, y, width, height, size, color, text)
    {
            this.isEnabled = false; //<---------------
    }
UI.BtnShape = BtnShape;
})();
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The only difference that I can see here is the order in which `isEnabled` property is set. By nesting the `isEnabled` property into the initialise function, you'd need to run the `initalise` procedure before the `isEnabled` has any value. I'd assume that you would run the initialise function before doing anything, but if you don't then `isEnabled` would be empty.

Answer (score 3):

1st way: `isEnabled` will be `false`, regardless of whether you called `initialise()` or not.

2nd way: `isEnabled` will be `false` only if you called `initialise()`, `undefined` otherwise.

Answer (score 1):

In first way, It is by default not enabled ( but not undefined)

```
// After all your code
var x= BtnShape.prototype;
// Here x is not enabled . If you want to enable it, you need to do it separately like below.
p.isEnabled = true;
```

In second way, when you initialize the object, by default it becomes false. Unless, you initialize, If you initialize, it becomes dialed. You need to separately enable it.

```
var y =BtnShape.prototype;
// Here if you don't initialize the object y, then isEnabled is undefined.
```